# Cookies Policy should it be added or not?

Tags: cookies, cookie-policy

We have a website where I store the user's country selection choice. I do not track it from their IP address or anything else.

Plus I use Google Analytics which also uses cookies to store some data. Should I state that GA uses cookies as it a service which I use for analytics?

Now I am confused whether to show a message saying that we use cookies to enhance the user's experience on out website.

Comment: Yes, you should. As you're using GA and is storing a cookie in client browser.

Comment: What kind of a message can I display for GA as well as user's country selection choice. Do I have to explicitly mention them in the message?

Comment: As far as I know, you only have to notify about the use of cookies saving some user data, don't have to make a deep explanation. So you can use a generic message, you can take a look around and find what keeps good for your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should show the consent even if a third party library uses them (eventually you use that data).
But you don't have to explicitly mention what is stored in cookies.

There are [open source multi language alternatives](https://silktide.com/tools/cookie-consent/) you can easily use to embed the concent into your UI.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexStack for sharing that URL.